# recyclerView touch listener using a button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
   recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new GalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new GalleryAdapter.ClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                //Values are passing to activity & to fragment as well

                int id = view.getId();


                    if(id == R.id.carasoul_button) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivityCarasoul.this, PDFViewerActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(PDFViewerActivity.TAG, books.get(position));
                        intent.putExtra("from", "mo2lfatActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }



            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
```

what this code does is when i click on the item in recycle view another activity will be opened, i wanna change that with a button that can be pressed that will open the activity.

I tried the above code and it didn't work. i put the button outside the RecycleView

The button is not in this xml  layout.gallery_thumbnail.If i put it here it will be in all the views. The button is in the main xml which has recycle view itself.

```
@Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

Comment: You have to use *custom adapter* to `recyclerView` and then set `onClickListener` to the button

Comment: @Khallad shahin, I have updated my answer. I hope, this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position of your item then just add a tag of that view in your `onBindViewHolder` method. Here is the code example:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.yourButton.setTag(position);
}
```

In your ViewHolder Constructor method, add onClickListener on your button.
here is sample:

```
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);
        Button yourButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);

        yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

  Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PDFViewerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PDFViewerActivity.TAG, ""+button.getTag());
                intent.putExtra("from","mo2lfatActivity");
                context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Here, context is the activity context, that can you pass by Adapter Constructor.

Thanks :)

Comment: i am getting an error in this line                     intent.putExtra(PDFViewerActivity.TAG, button.getTag());

Comment: Bro, what is the error? you can add  button.getTag().toString() to convert it to string

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: What id your button Id? Initialize your button with your button id from xml. That will solve your problem.
Follow this link
http://stackoverflow.com/q/13374125/3073945

Comment: this is not the problem. The problem is that the button is not in this class    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail, parent, false);  if i put it in this one layout.gallery_thumbnail it will be copied in all of them

Comment: the button is in the main activity

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewHolder` class you can set `OnClickListener` for that button and override `onClick()` method to open another activity.

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public Button btMyButton;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        btMyButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bt_my_button);
        btMyButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.bt_my_button){
           Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PDFViewerActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra(PDFViewerActivity.TAG, books.get(getAdapterPosition()));
           intent.putExtra("from","mo2lfatActivity");
           startActivity(intent);               
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
    itemViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent Code
        }
    });
}
```

This will work..

Answer (score 0):

This is working code. I have tested it. You have to define your button click inside adapter. And it will work like charm. Let me know if you face any issue.

```
/**
 * Created by Alok on 4/18/2017.
 */

public class DealsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DealsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    private List<Deal> dealsLists;
    private static String listType = "OFFER";

    public DealsRecyclerAdapter(){

    }

    public DealsRecyclerAdapter(Activity a, Context c, List<Deal> d, String listType){
        this.context = c;
        this.dealsLists = d;
        this.activity = a;
        this.listType = listType;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public CardView dealListCardView;
        public ImageView imgDish;
        public TextView txtRestaurantName, txtDishName, txtDishPrice, txtDishAvailabilty;
        public Button btnOrderNow, btnBookTable;
        public ImageButton btnCallNow;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            dealListCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dealListCardView);
            imgDish = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDish);
            txtRestaurantName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRestaurantName);
            txtDishName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDishName);
            txtDishPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDishPrice);
            txtDishAvailabilty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDishAvailabilty);

            btnOrderNow = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnOrderNow);
            btnBookTable = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnBookTable);
            btnCallNow = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCallNow);

            if(listType == "OFFER"){
                txtDishAvailabilty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                txtDishAvailabilty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DealsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.special_offer, parent, false);
        v.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Deal deals = dealsLists.get(position);

        Picasso
                .with(context)
                .load(DEV_URL_SERVER + deals.getImgpath())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
                .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                .into(holder.imgDish);

        holder.txtRestaurantName.setText(deals.getRestaurantName());
        holder.txtDishName.setText(deals.getName());
        holder.txtDishPrice.setText(String.valueOf(deals.getFinalcost()));

        if(deals.getSoldout()) {
            holder.txtDishAvailabilty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btnOrderNow.setClickable(false);
            holder.btnOrderNow.setEnabled(false);
            holder.btnBookTable.setClickable(false);
            holder.btnBookTable.setEnabled(false);
        }

        holder.btnOrderNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((SearchActivity)activity).setShPref(KEY_REST_ID, String.valueOf(deals.getRestaurantId()));
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, RestaurantOverviewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("FROM_ACTIVITY", "SearchActivity");
                intent.putExtra("RESTID", deals.getRestaurantId());
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.btnBookTable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((SearchActivity)activity).setShPref(KEY_REST_ID, String.valueOf(deals.getRestaurantId()));
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(activity, BookTableActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("FROM_ACTIVITY", "SearchActivity");
                intent1.putExtra("RESTID", deals.getRestaurantId());
                activity.startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

        holder.btnCallNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + deals.getPhone()));
                try {
                    activity.startActivity(intent3);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  dealsLists == null ? 0 : dealsLists.size();
    }

    public void notify(List<Deal> list) {
        if (dealsLists != null) {
            dealsLists.clear();
            dealsLists.addAll(list);
        } else {
            dealsLists = list;
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First, add implementation to your activity:**

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   // do your stuff
}
```

This:

```
buttonname.setOnClickListener(this);
```

means that you want to assign listener for your Button "on this instance" -> this instance represents OnClickListener and for this reason your class have to implement that interface.

It's similar with anonymous listener class (that you can also use):

```
buttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View view) {
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new GalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new GalleryAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            // Values are passing to activity & to fragment as well
            // Toast.makeText(mainActivityCarasoul.this, "Single Click on position: "+position,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivityCarasoul.this, PDFViewerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PDFViewerActivity.TAG, books.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("from","mo2lfatActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
   }
});
```